# RestKit objectModeling dynamic data

Tags: objective-c, ios, json, rest, restkit

Is it possible to use key mapping with the following JSON structure or are we going to have to perform looping through values manually?  Examples would be great. Their rest api doesn't really map real world objects into a standard object structure, but just modeled after the XML attributes. :(

```
THINGS{
"lastModifiedDate": "2012-02-23-08.43.16.916000",
"myList": [{
  "attributeList": [
                    {"id": "","name": "Content Level","val": "Introductory"},
                    {"id": "","name": "Session Type","val": "Business Overview"},
                    {"id": "20110616053537016","name": "Speaker","val": "Jim Kim, Company1"},
                    {"id": "20110616053526559","name": "Speaker","val": "Bob Ironman, Company2"},
                    {"id": "20110803145027914","name": "Speaker","val": "Kristine Thomas, Company3"},
                    {"id": "","name": "Room","val": "Banyan"},
                    {"id": "","name": "Industry","val": "Cross Industry"},
                    {"id": "","name": "Loc","val": "Stadium I"},
                    {"id": "","name": "Topic Tag","val": "CMS Systems"},
                    {"id": "","name": "Status","val": "Accepted"},
                    {"id": "","name": "Sub-Event","val": "Leadership"},
                    {"id": "","name": "Session","val": "LVI"},
                    {"id": "","name": "SubTrack","val": "None"},
                    {"id": "","name": "Track","val": "Business Value Outsourcing"}
  ],

"active": true,
"desc": "This is a really cool thing",
"end": "16:00",
"id": "2011080146112",
"num": "1002A",
"start": "15:00",
"title": "The thing title"
  }
 ]
}
```

Comment: Hi, jgervin you are expecting THINGS to be just one element right?

Comment: Do different THINGS have different entries in attributeList?

Comment: Yes, the attributeList is dynamic and can be anything. It will be this way one time and a month later something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible with RestKit.

You can get all documentation you need reading this article from the official [wiki](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/blob/master/Docs/Object%20Mapping.md) and here you have an explanation for doing what you need. Hope this helps you!

First you will need three objects for each entity, one for the ThingsList, another for representing one Thing and another for representing one ThingAttribute. Let's start by the most basic element, the ThingAttribute:

**SOAttribute.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface SOAttribute : NSObject{
    NSNumber *attributeId; //I use this nomenclature because the word 'id' is reserved, same for other objects.
    NSString *name;
    NSString *val;
}

@end
```

**SOAttribute.m**

```
@implementation SOAttribute
@end
```

This will let you to represent this part of the JSON:

```
{"id": "","name": "Content Level","val": "Introductory"}
```

Now we will define the Thing as follows:

**SOThing.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface SOThing : NSObject{

    NSArray *attributeList; //This represent the list of attributes defined before
    BOOL active;
    NSString *desc;
    NSString *title;
    NSString *end;
    NSString *start;
    NSString *num;
    NSNumber *thingId;

}

@end
```

**SOThing.m**

```
#import "SOThing.h"
@implementation SOThing
@end
```

As you can notice, you have to define the attributeList as an NSArray. RestKit automatically will know that you need to receive a list of attributes there. So we have defined the following structure:

```
{
    "attributeList": [...],
    "active": true,
    "desc": "This is a really cool thing",
    "end": "16:00",
    "id": "2011080146112",
    "num": "1002A",
    "start": "15:00",
    "title": "The thing title"
}
```

Finally you define the Thing List as follows:

**SOThingList.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface SOThingList : NSObject{
    NSDate *lastModifiedDate;
    NSArray *myList;
}
@end
```

**SoThingList.m**

```
#import "SOThingList.h"
@implementation SOThingList
@end
```

As before, we need a list of Things so we define myList as an NSArray.

Now, that was easy, here comes the magic where you indicate to RestKit how to map each entity.
On your App Delegate put the following code:

```
#import "SOThingList.h"
#import "SOThing.h"
#import "SOAttribute.h"

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions{


    RKObjectMappingProvider *mappingProvider = [RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider;

    RKObjectMapping *mappingForAttribute = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[SOAttribute class]];
    //This can be mapped directly
    [mappingForAttribute mapAttributes:@"name",@"val", nil];
    //here you indicate the special case, id->attributeId on our object
    [mappingForAttribute mapKeyPath:@"id" toAttribute:@"attributeId"];
    //Set the new mapping into the mapping provider.
    [mappingProvider addObjectMapping:mappingForAttribute];

    RKObjectMapping *mappingForThing = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[SOThing class]];
    //Same as before, these attributes can be mapped directly
    [mappingForThing mapAttributes:@"active",@"title",@"end",@"start",@"desc",@"num", nil];
    [mappingForThing mapKeyPath:@"id" toAttribute:@"thingId"];
    //Here I indicate that any object on NSArray on attributeList should be mapped using SOAttribute mapping defined above.
    [mappingForThing mapKeyPath:@"attributeList" toRelationship:@"attributeList" withMapping:mappingForAttribute];
    [mappingProvider addObjectMapping:mappingForThing];

    RKObjectMapping *mappingForThingsList = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[SOThingList class]];
    [mappingForThingsList mapAttributes:@"lastModifiedDate", nil];
    [mappingForThingsList mapKeyPath:@"myList" toRelationship:@"myList" withMapping:mappingForThing];
    [mappingProvider addObjectMapping:mappingForThingsList];

}
```

After all the above, you can get your Thing List with the following method using blocks:

**SomeObject.m**

```
- (void) get: (NSString *) resourcePath onLoad:(RKObjectLoaderDidLoadObjectBlock) loadBlock onError:(RKRequestDidFailLoadWithErrorBlock)failBlock{

    RKObjectMapping *mapping = [[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider objectMappingForClass:[SOThingList class]];
    [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] loadObjectsAtResourcePath:resourcePath usingBlock:^(RKObjectLoader* loader) {
        loader.objectMapping = mapping;
        loader.delegate = self;
        loader.onDidLoadObject = loadBlock;

        loader.onDidFailWithError = ^(NSError * error){
            NSLog(@"%@",error);
        };
        loader.onDidFailLoadWithError = failBlock;
        loader.onDidLoadResponse = ^(RKResponse *response) {
            //Do something
        };

    }];

}
```

And you use it like this...

```
[someObjectInstance get:@"http://mydomain.com/mywebservice/" onLoad:^(id object){
    SOThingList *thingList = (SOThingList *) object;
    //Do something with your shiny thingList
} onError:^(NSError *error) {
    //Display an error message :)
}];
```

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed answer, but not quite there yet. I don't want or need the SOAttribute object.  What I need is for Restkit to map in the SOThing class the items in that you list in the SOAttribute class.  So turn this [ eg. {"id": "","name": "Content Level","val": "Introductory"}
]  into properties on the SOThing like this "Content Level":"Introductory" I am trying to get rid of the name:blah val:blah.   Since the API sends over all the attributeList garage I want those attributeList items turned into specific properties or an array of specific properties.

Comment: These properties are defined or arbitrary? I'm not really sure but I think maybe you can achieve what you want using Dynamic Object Mapping. Could you post an example of the object you want to get?

Comment: I think you will not be able to "dynamically" modify the SOThing object to have properties like ContentLevel using RestKit. On the other side maybe you could build a dictionary as you mention with Key: "Content Level" and value "Introduction" with dynamic mapping. But I don't know how you want to map the property when you have an id... could you give an example?

Comment: That is why I started this question. Today they have a giant loop that loops through each arbitrary object (attriblist) and builds out NSDictionaries.  I wanted a seamless Mapping so I don't have NSDictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

You could always use a tool like Objectify ($15 US) or JSON Accelerator ($0.99 US) from the Mac App Store to help generate models for this JSON. Then when you have the array you could  use something like NSArray's

`- (void)makeObjectsPerformSelector:(SEL)aSelector`

To have all the objects look for an object.

Personally I'd prefer using blocks and

`- (void)enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:(void (^)(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop))block` to loop through things

It's not directly related to RestKit, but that may be a way to help you out.